# How is the database location decided when creating a copy using SQL Management client API?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, service-management

This is the code to create a database copy in Azure using service management api's

```
SqlManagementClient sqlClient = new SqlManagementClient sqlClient ();
DatabaseCopyCreateParameters newDatabaseParameters = new DatabaseCopyCreateParameters()
                    {
                        IsContinuous = true,
                        PartnerDatabase = srcDB
                        PartnerServer = srcserver
                    };
sqlClient.DatabaseCopies.Create(dbservername, dbname, newDatabaseParameters);
```

It got created in the location say "east asia".

As you can see I am not providing any location details, then how it is created in this location?

Answer (score 0):

Location is decided based on the server location. Since my server is in East Asia, Obviously db will be in East Asia

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid this by copying the database using T-SQL as explained below:

```
-- Execute on the master database of the target server (server2)
-- Start copying from Server1 to Server2
CREATE DATABASE Database1_copy AS COPY OF server1.Database1;
```

For more information, click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy).

Hope this helps.